# Check condition in if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I have seen code like this:

```
$result1 = someFunction();

if ($result1) {
    /* some follow up logic */
}
```

I am not quite sure what does if ($result1) mean, normally when we check condition in if statement, it should be something that can be generated true or false explicitly, so the syntax should be if (true) or if (false), for example, if (1==1) is equivalent to if (true), so how about if ($result1)? $result1 itself doesn't generate true or false.

Comment: This is where type casting come into play. In this case, PHP uses the result of `$result1` cast to a boolean true or false. Have a read of http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: `mysqli_query()` returns always false if something did go wrong. If the query succeeded, it returns the result that is not false. So the statement is true.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:

1. [PHP: Expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php)
2. [PHP: if](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)
3. [PHP: Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

---

Excerpt about `if` statement from documentation:

```
if (expr)
    statement
```

Expression (`expr`) is evaluated to its Boolean value. If expression evaluates to `TRUE`, PHP will execute statement, and if it evaluates to `FALSE` - it'll ignore it.

And again from the documentation about expressions:

> The simplest yet most accurate way to define an expression is **"anything that has a value"**.

Now, `$result1` is an expression, which has a value. So, the expression `$result1` will be converted to a boolean value and will be used in the `if` statement.