# Why do functions execute in PHP if statements?

Tags: php

So the syntax for if statements is:

```
if(condition){
    //code to execute
}
```

Then why do functions when placed in place of conditions work in PHP.

Comment: Why not? Why a condition is somewhat better than a function?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Is this a real question *"Then why do functions when placed in place of conditions work in PHP"*? .... Why do you buy stuff at a store IF you went in there to buy stuff? ... So it's not a real question. OP is trolling. +1 @YourCommonSense +1 Masiorama

Comment: @GetSet tbh it's a legit question. but more on a software architecture

Comment: How @YourCommonSense is an if block from purely (perhaps philosophical) separated from any discipline? I'd say to think that an "if statement" or any statement where a condition is checked before execution, to run *anyway* is theological to see what it does.

Comment: @GetSet that's what has to be explained here. The concept of a statement, expression, operator. What they are and how they interact.

Comment: Oh you mean if the condition can contain functions that in turn "on stack" get resolved, other values can get assigned with or without anything being "called" in the condition. But if you think about it, the native raw "condition" to do a raw *branch* is cut and clear.

Comment: By the way, @ArpanAcharya specifically for mysqlu functions, they should never be put inside conditions, simply because there is not single sensible reason to do so.

Comment: @YourCommonSense That last comment seems weirdly absolute. I'm pretty sure there are mysqli functions which return a boolean to indicate success, so would be perfectly sensible to call in an if condition. Even those which return false on failure and an object on success can be used that way in some scenarios.

Comment: @IMSoP a function that throws an exception on error will never return false. And checking for true only makes no sense

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'm not that familiar with it (I've always used PDO) but [the manual for mysqli_query](https://www.php.net/mysqli_query) says it returns false on failure. Perhaps there's a mode to throw exceptions instead, like PDO?

Comment: @IMSoP yes, there is. The usage example on this page exactly demonstrates this correct approach, with setting the mode and avoiding the unnecessary conditions

Comment: Relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44907939/check-condition

Comment: @IMSoP "*it returns false on failure*" So does `PDO::query()` and yet most users don't put it in an if statement

Comment: @Dharman The comment I was originally responding to didn't talk about "most users", it said "never" and "not a single reason". If you're using the mode where errors return false, then there are absolutely legitimate reasons to put it in an if statement.

Answer (score 3):

In PHP (and many languages) there is no specific concept of a "condition"; the actual definition of an if statement is:

```
if(expression){
    //code to execute
}
```

An "expression" is simply anything that can be evaluated and results in a value. A single value, like `42` is an expression on its own, as is a simple sum like `1 + 1`. A function call like `strlen('hello')` is also an expression, evaluating to the result of the function; the function has to be run, *which may have side effects*, to determine that result. Expressions can be arbitrarily complex by linking then with operators, like `strlen('hello') * 2 + 1`.

Commonly in an if statement, you'd have something like `$foo === $bar` - this is just an expression that uses the `===` operator to give a boolean result, either `true` or `false`. PHP will evaluate that expression, and then decide whether to run the conditional code based on the result. The expression can be as simple or complex as you want - `if(true)` is valid, though not often useful, and so is `if((strlen('hello') * 2 + 1) > 10)`.

If the result of the expression is not a boolean, PHP "coerces" it into one, as described on [the manual page about the boolean type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php). For instance `strlen($foo)` evaluates to an integer, and all integers other than zero coerce to `true`, so `if(strlen($foo))` acts like `if(strlen($foo) !== 0)`.

As well as function calls, there are other expressions which have side effects. For instance, an *assignment* can also be used as an expression, evaluating to the value assigned. This lets you do things like `$foo = $bar = 0;` where `$foo` is assigned the result of running `$bar = 0;` which is of course `0`. It also lets you put assignments inside if statements, like `if ( $result = getData() ) { ... }`, which is shorthand for `$result = getData(); if ( $result ) { ... }` This technique should be used with care, though, because at a glance it can be hard to spot the difference between `=` (assignment) and `==` (weak comparison).

Answer (score 1):

The values returned in a PHP **if** condition are not restricted to be "strictly" Boolean, however the condition is expected to be Boolean. Why? Because all PHP variables types (inbuilt or user-defined) can be implicitly type-casted (converted automatically) to Boolean. According to the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php):

> To explicitly convert a value to bool, use the (bool) or (boolean) casts. However, in most cases the cast is unnecessary, since a value will be automatically converted if an operator, function or control structure requires a bool argument.

The [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) also explicitly specifies the falsy values for the different variable types including user defined types with all other values not specified being truthy:

> the following values are considered false:

> - the boolean false itself
> - the integer 0 (zero)
> - the floats 0.0 and -0.0 (zero)
> - the empty string, and the string "0"
> - an array with zero elements
> - the special type NULL (including unset variables)
> - SimpleXML objects created from attributeless empty elements, i.e. elements which have neither children nor attributes.

> Every other value is considered true (including any resource and NAN).

Therefore, to explicitly answer your question:

> why do functions when placed in place of conditions work in PHP?

One reason I know of, is so you can conveniently perform assignments in the conditions:

```php
function inverse_power($base, $exp)
{
    if($power = pow($base, $exp)) {
        return 1/$power;
    }
    else {
        return "logical error: you can't divide by zero";
    }
}

echo inverse_power(2,1); // 0.5
echo inverse_power(0,1); // logical error: you can't divide by zero
```

From the above example, you see the feature saves me multiple lines of code. Note that `$power` is not explicitly Boolean, but will be automatically converted to Boolean **only** to test the condition. The actual value of `$power` still persists throughout the function.

Comment: I agree with all of this, until you get to the part about assignments. That's not *why* it works, and I'd say it's not a good habit to get into, as it's easy to misread the `=` as an `==`. It doesn't even meet the rather vague question, since it's not a function call, it's an assignment statement.

Comment: @IMSoP, "That's not why it works". Yes. But, it's one of the reasons you can place function calls in PHP if conditions. So, it is one reason, it works. Not the only reason though.

Comment: No, the *reason* it works is that, as my answer says, there is no separate concept of "condition" in PHP's grammar, so there's nothing to *stop* it working. Using an assignment as an expression is really quite an "exotic" example, compared to a straightforward function call like `if (is_int($foo))`, or an expression involving one like `if(strlen($foo) > 5)`

Comment: @IMSoP, you *interestingly* included this "exotic" case in the last paragraph of your answer. :). However, except I was the inventor of the PHP language, I wouldn't know the exact reason. But I know what it allows to be validly possible. Yes, the questioner was a little bit vague in asking for the "reason", Which would require an assertive answer from the creators of the PHP language.

Comment: I included it as an unusual *consequence* of some other design decisions, because you'd already mentioned it. We don't need to know the exact history to know that it's *incredibly unlikely* that function calls are only allowed because assignments are - if you couldn't put assignments in if statements, most people wouldn't care; if you couldn't put *any function calls at all* in if statements, that would be a huge nuisance. My main point is that there are many much simpler examples you could have chosen.

Answer (score -1):

Because a condition is a boolean and functions can return booleans. And for conditions to work, the condition itself has to be evaluated, so it can be a function that is executed also.

Comment: Does PHP have the concept of truthy/falsey? Then it doesn't have to be a boolean.

Comment: Truthy/Falsey is implied by any return value that is not checked on equality of pure boolean. No matter the language. Javascript did not invent the concept but simply documented it.

Comment: Functions do not necessarily have to return Boolean, to be put in a PHP if condition. See my answer.